# why 'tns' prefix is not required in type element in wsdl files?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to learn `wsdl` as a fresher. I have no complete understanding of XML or anything for that matter. I just know the basics. I see the basic types in wsdl are generally xml schema so `xsd:string` etc are used.

My Question is :

In WSDL type element, inside it the `tns` prefix is not used like it is used for operations element. Why?

I have attached the excerpt from a tutorial site.

```
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs=        "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace= "http://jenkov.com/MyService/schema"
    xmlns:tns=       "http://jenkov.com/MyService/schema">

    <xs:element name="latestTutorialRequest" type="typeLatestTutorialRequest"/>
    <xs:complexType name="typeLatestTutorialRequest">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element  name="date"   type="xs:date"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="latestTutorialResponse" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="invalidDateError" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Shouldn't it be..

```
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs=        "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace= "http://jenkov.com/MyService/schema"
    xmlns:tns=       "http://jenkov.com/MyService/schema">

    <xs:element name="latestTutorialRequest" type="**tns:typeLatestTutorialRequest**"/>
    <xs:complexType name="typeLatestTutorialRequest">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="date" type="xs:date"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="latestTutorialResponse" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="invalidDateError" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, the schema as written is wrong. This is what Saxon has to say about it:

```
Saxon-EE 9.8.0.6J from Saxonica
Java version 1.8.0_121
Using license serial number V005192
Loading schema document file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xsd
Error at xs:element on line 6 column 80 of test.xsd:
  Cannot reference schema components in the null namespace as it has not been imported
Schema processing failed: One error was found while processing the schema
```